# Javascript redirect is only refreshing page

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a javascript function that looks like:

```
function logout() {

alert('logging out 2');
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

}
```

The alert pops up but the page refreshes when I want it to go to stackoverflow.com (for testing purposes). Why would this be?

Comment: try `window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";`

Comment: The same thing happens with that code :/

Comment: Where's the `logout` function declared and how/where/when is it called?

Comment: Sure you did `href = "`, and that you didn't do `href("`?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('#logout').click(function() {
  logout();
 });
 
});

Comment: Yes I'm sure I copied it directly.

Comment: Fair enough... I think epascarello has just had the brain-wave we've been looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you are not cancelling the click event of the element that is calling the function so the page is refreshing. Cancel the click event.

```
onclick="logout(); return false;"
```

or use preventDefault

---

From the comments

```
$('#logout').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); logout(); });
```

Comment: Why does that cause the page to refresh?

Comment: because you probably have like href="" in that link and the browser is finishing off the motions to follow it, which is reloading the page. `return false` or using `.preventDefault()` will prevent the browser from following what's in the href

Comment: Because the link/button or whatever you are calling is still doing its default action. You need to tell it to stop.